# strcpy not working with string pointer in a class

Tags: c++, string, class, oop, object

I'm new to c++.I made a simple program that name members of class based on your input.
But for some reason, compiler shows this error - `'str': is not a member of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'`, I have trouble understanding what it means.
Please help me out
here is my code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class mystring
{
private:
    std::string *str;

public:
    //constructors
    mystring();
    mystring(const std::string &strthing);
    ~mystring();

    //methods
    void display() const;
};


mystring::mystring()                                                    //defalt constructor
    :str(nullptr)
{}

mystring::mystring(const std::string& strthing)                         //copy constructor
    :str(nullptr)
{
    delete str;
    str = new std::string;
    strcpy(this->str, strthing.str);
    std::cout << "overloaded\n";
}
mystring::~mystring()                                                   //destructor
{
    delete [] str;
}

void mystring::display() const                                          //display func
{
    std::cout << *str;
}

int main()
{
    mystring thing;
    mystring object{ "samurai" };
    object.display();

}
```

I think something is wrong with the `strcpy()` function in overloaded constructor.
Thanks

Comment: There are many typos, try to fix them

Comment: strcpy is for C strings

Comment: You seem to be confusing the `std::string` class with C-style `char*` strings.

Comment: `strcpy(this->str, strthing.str);` should be `*this->str = strthing.str;`. Also you should follow [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: The chances you need `str` to be a *pointer to* `std::string` rather than simply a `std::string` are extremely remote, likewise calling into question the very need for `mystring` in the first place.

Comment: Also `delete [] str;` is bad because `str` is not allocated via `new[]`.

Comment: btw writing your own string class is by no means "simple". Fixing all problems with your `mystring` is a worthwhile exercise but I think you underestimate it. Don't miss to read about the [rule of 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with `strcpy`, but with how you use it. `std::string`s can be copied with their `operator=`:

```
 std::string a;
 std::string b;
 a = b;            // copy b to a
```

`strcpy` on the other hand is for c-strings, which a `std::string` is not:

```
char* strcpy( char* dest, const char* src );
```

It is unclear why you have a member of type pointer to `std::string`. You should either use a `std::string` (no pointer), or if this is an exercise to write your own string class (not an easy one!) then you should probably store the data in an array of `char`s.

The error you get is about `strthing.str`. Here `strthing` is a `std::string` which has no `str` member. If that constructor is supposed to be a copy constructor it should take a `const mystring&` as parameter not a `const std::string&`.

Comment: thanks, after reading your answer i tried do this `this->*str = strthing.*str;` but it gives me this error -`->*': illegal, right operand has type 'std::string *'`

Comment: @default-303 it would be `*str = *(strthing.str);`

Comment: so you men i cannot use `this->` and `.*` in my code?Is that the syntax im supposed to stick to??

Comment: @default-303 you can use `this->` but inside member functions it is redundant. Inside the member function `str` does already refer to the member called `str`

Comment: @default-303 it would be `*this->str = *strthing.str;`. With brackets it does this: `*(this->str) = *(strthing.str);` First you get strthing.str (which is a pointer), then you look at the thing it points to with *

Comment: @i know this-> refers to inside member function, but it feels more easy to understand in early stages if i use that.Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

This is just a typo.

```
 mystring::mystring(const std::string& strthing)
```

Should be

```
mystring::mystring(const mystring& strthing)
```

Comment: not "just" there will still be a call to `strcpy` with pointers to `std::string`

Comment: That wasn't what the question was asking about

Comment: OP never said expliticly that they intended to write a copy constructor, so you should also take into account other possibilities

Comment: oh sorry, they did ;)

Comment: Yah I'm just addressing the reported compilation error. OP can work on fixing other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `strcpy` to copy `std::string` objects. Here's your constructor rewritten correctly (it's not a copy constructor because it doesn't copy `mystring` objects)

```
mystring::mystring(const std::string& strthing) // constructor from std::string
    : str(new std::string(strthing)) // allocate new string by copying from strthing
{
    std::cout << "overloaded\n";
}
```

Because your class allocates memory (not sure why it does but it does) you do actually need to write a genuine copy constructor and assignment operator

```
mystring::mystring(const mystring& strthing) // copy constructor

mystring& mystring::operator=(const mystring& strthing) // assignment operator
```

But I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ther is a C++ trap between C++ type `std::string` and C type 'char*'.

`std::string` can convert to `char*` using `std::string.c_str()`.

And `strcpy` takes `char*` and `char const *` as parameters.

In moderen C++ practice, use `std::string` usually, `std::string *` is not recommended  to use.

If you want to use `strcpy` with `std::string`, you have to do the conversion between `char *` and `std::string`. Below is a simple Example:

```
    std::string dest;
    std::string source = "Hello, World!";
    char temp[40];
    strcpy(temp, source.c_str());
    dest = temp;
```